# How to get WSO2 property values using xpath?

Tags: xpath, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have a property called body containing xml value

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request xmlns="http://api-v1.gen.mm.example.com/mminterface/request">
   <Transaction>
      <Origin>country 1</Origin>
   </Transaction>
</request>
```

wanted to get origin from the property using xpath or expression in wso2.

And the result to be appearing like this

```
<Origin>country 1</Origin>
```

or

```
country 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get property as XML from other property eg named `body` you can use:

`<property expression="$ctx:body//Transaction/*" name="Origin" type="OM"/>`

And for text value you can use:

`<property expression="$ctx:body//Origin/text()" name="Origin" type="STRING"/>`

And then try retrieve the value

If it not work, make sure your property is of type OM or you can try convert type STRING to OM using property like:
`<property expression="$ctx:body" name="body" type="OM"/>`

Comment: thanks for answering but the xml is inside a property called body, i wanted to fetch from it(body)

Comment: Ok, a add additional info

Answer (score 1):

Try this `XPath` query:

```
//Origin/text()
```